# Multiple rows into One Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, string-aggregation

My volatile table in Teradata contains data like the following.

```
  ID |  RECORD_TIMESTAMP |  CHANNEL
1    |    20200101       |  A
1    |    20200102       |  B
1    |    20200103       |  C
2    |    20200104       |  D
3    |    20200105       |  E
```

My required output is to concatenate the data based on ID and delimit with pipe. The ID may or maynot have multiple instances (multiple instances go upto 50 per ID)

**Required Output**:

```
1|20200101|A|1|20200102|B|1|20200103|C
2|20200104|D
3|20200105|E
```

How can we achieve this? I tried self-join which were creating duplicates, tried XMLAGG, but couldnt replicate the format i needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```sql
SELECT ID, 
  TRIM(TRAILING '|' FROM (
    XMLAGG(
      ID || '|' || RECORD_TIMESTAMP || '|' || CHANNEL || '|' -- value to group
      ORDER BY ID, RECORD_TIMESTAMP, CHANNEL -- group ordering
    ) 
    (VARCHAR(1000))
    )
  ) AS MyRecordGroups
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked for a low volume of data in the table. The actual table had 77 mil records. And it Failed with error : 3156 , Request aborted by TDWM. Exception criteria : CPU Time. Is there any work around without seeking DBA help?

Comment: No problem.  Hmm...the best way would be to do the `GROUP BY` using an indexed field in your table -- is `ID` the primary index?  If not, can you possibly add a secondary index and collect statistics on it?  Also, try running an `EXPLAIN` on the query to see which step could be causing the issue.